# Slow boot on Asus ROG GL552vw

Tags: 16.04, boot-time

My Asus ROG GL552vw has a very slow boot of Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. I'm booting single boot. `nomodeset` doesn't work. I've attached some things with the post showing `systemd-analyze time`, etc. It takes about 1 minute to boot. After grub there is a blank purple screen for 50 seconds, then ten seconds of splash screen. `fstab` checks out.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Having read your question carefully while editing it I am unable to understand why it was downvoted and the downvoter didn't leave a comment explaining why it was downvoted, so I upvoted it back to zero to correct this.

Comment: thank you but i'm very confused about this problem